# Converting xml data into list of dictionaries to load into tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have written a code to convert xml data into list of dictionaries and load into tables.

**Input file data:**

```
<report>
    <report_header type='comp1'  title='industry' year='2019' />
        <report_body age='21'>
        <Prod name='krishna' id='11' place='usa'>
            <License state='aus' area= 'street1'>
            </License>
            <License state='mus' area= 'street2'>
            </License>
            <License state='mukin' area= 'street3'>
            </License>
        </Prod>
        <Prod name='ram' id='12' place='uk'>
            <License state='junej' area= 'street4'>
            </License>
            <License state='rand' area= 'street5'>
            </License>
            <License state='gandhi' area= 'street6'>
            </License>
        </Prod>
        <Prod name='chand' id='13' place='london'>
            <License state='nehru' area= 'street7'>
            </License>
            <License state='mahatma' area= 'street8'>
            </License>
            <License state='park' area= 'street9'>
            </License>
        </Prod>
    </report_body>
 </report>
```

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
way_list=[]
for item in root.iter():
  way_list.append(dict(item.attrib))
for k, v in [(k, v) for x in way_list for (k, v) in x.items()]:
  print(k,v)
```

**output:** 
type comp1

title industry

year 2019

age 21

name krishna

id 11

place usa

state aus

area street1

state mus

area street2

state mukin

area street3

name ram

id 12

place uk

state junej

area street4

state rand

area street5

state gandhi

area street6

name chand

id 13

place london

state nehru

area street7

state mahatma

area street8

state park

area street9

**Expected Output:** [{type:'comp1',title:'industry',year:2019,age:21,name:'krishna',id:11,place:'usa',state :'aus',area:'street1'},{type:'comp1',title:'industry',year:2019,age:21,name:'krishna',id:11,place:'usa',state :'mus',area:'street2'},{type:'comp1',title:'industry',year:2019,age:21,name:'krishna',id:11,place:'usa',state :'muskin',area:'street3'},{type:'comp1',title:'industry',year:2019,age:21,name:'ram',id:12,place:'uk',state :'junej',area:'street4'},{type:'comp1',title:'industry',year:2019,age:21,name:'ram',id:12,place:'uk',state :'rand',area:'street5'},.........etc]

My main aim is to load data into table like below:

**type,title,year,name,id,place,state,area**

comp1,industry,2019,krishna,11,usa,aus,street1

comp1,industry,2019,krishna,11,usa,mus,street2

comp1,industry,2019,krishna,11,usa,muskin,street3

comp1,industry,2019,ram,12,uk,junej,street4

comp1,industry,2019,ram,12,uk,rand,street5

comp1,industry,2019,ram,12,uk,gandhi,street6

Now, im able to convert data into list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Read up on the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

```
import csv, os, sys, io
from xml.etree import ElementTree

data = """\
<report>
<report_header type='comp1'  title='industry' year='2019' />
    <report_body>
    <Prod name='krishna' id='11' place='usa'>
        <License state='aus' area= 'street1'>
        </License>
        <License state='mus' area= 'street2'>
        </License>
        <License state='mukin' area= 'street3'>
        </License>
    </Prod>
    <Prod name='ram' id='12' place='uk'>
        <License state='junej' area= 'street4'>
        </License>
        <License state='rand' area= 'street5'>
        </License>
        <License state='gandhi' area= 'street6'>
        </License>
    </Prod>
    <Prod name='chand' id='13' place='london'>
        <License state='nehru' area= 'street7'>
        </License>
        <License state='mahatma' area= 'street8'>
        </License>
        <License state='park' area= 'street9'>
        </License>
    </Prod>
</report_body>
</report>
"""

fieldnames = ['type', 'title', 'year', 'name', 'id', 'place', 'state', 'area']
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
tree = ElementTree.parse(io.StringIO(data))
report_header = tree.find('report_header')
report_body = tree.find('report_body')
for Prod in report_body.findall('Prod'):
    for License in Prod.findall('License'):
        d = {}
        d.update(License.attrib)
        d.update(Prod.attrib)
        d.update(report_header.attrib)
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

using just ElementTree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dict_rep= root.find('report_header').attrib
dict_rep.update(root.find('report_body').attrib)
way_list=[]
for prod in root.iter('Prod'):
  dict_line = dict_rep
  dict_line.update(prod.attrib)
  for lic in prod.iter('License'):
    dict_line.update(lic.attrib)
    print(dict_line)
    way_list.append(dict_line)
```